# If $A$ is an Abelian group and $B < A$, $ A \simeq B \simeq \mathbb Z^n$ for some natural $n$. Prove that $mA \subset B $ for some $m$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

If $A$ is an Abelian group and $B < A$, $ A \simeq B \simeq \mathbb Z^n$ for some natural $n$. Prove that $mA \subset B $ for some $m$.

I know this has something to do with the fact that there exists bases for both A and B, but I don't understand what $mA$ denotes. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is $B < A$?

Comment: @Jihad Widespread notation for "subspace" .

Comment: @Jihad it means $B$ is a subgroup of $A$.

Comment: $A$ is abelian group so multiplication by natural number is defined pretty well.

Comment: @William  $$mA:=\{ma\;:\; a\in A\}\; $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the following theorem:

*There exists a (free) basis $\;\{a_1,...,a_n\}\;$ of $\;A\;$ and integers $\;d_1,...,d_n\;$ s.t. $\;\{d_1a_1,...,d_na_n\}\;$ is a (free) basis of $\;B\;$*

Now just take $\;m:=d_1\cdot\ldots\cdot d_n\;$

Remark: The above quoted theorem is  stronger and the integers can be chosen as to fulfill some divisibility properties, but we don't care about this now.

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality, we may assume that $A$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb Q^n$.

Then $A \simeq B \simeq \mathbb Z^n$ implies that the $\mathbb Q$-subspaces generated by $A$ and $B$ are both equal to $\mathbb Q^n$. In particular, both $A$ and $B$ contain bases for $\mathbb Q^n$.

Write the basis in $A$ in terms of the basis in $B$. Then $mA \subset B$ for $m$ equal to denominator of the determinant of the basis transformation matrix.

Answer (score 0):

We have the following exact sequence
$$
0 \rightarrow B \rightarrow A \rightarrow A/B \rightarrow 0. 
$$

Since $B \cong A \cong \mathbb{Z}^n, A/B \cong \bigoplus_{i = 1}^r \mathbb{Z}/d_i\mathbb{Z},$ for some $d_1, d_2, \cdots , d_r \in \mathbb{N}.$ Take $m = \prod_{i = 1}^r d_i.$ Then $mA = 0$ in the quotient group, i.e. $mA \subseteq B.$

Comment: Certainly $r=n$, otherwise...

Comment: @user26857: not necessarily. I didn't say that $d_i$'s are prime powers. for example, take $n = 2$ and choose basis for $A$ and $B$ respectively as follows: $\{e_1, e_2\}$ and $\{6e_1, 6e_2\}.$ in this case $A/B = \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}.$

Comment: I think $A/B\simeq(\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z)^2$.

Comment: yes. you are right. now take $d_1 =2, d_2 = 2, d_3 = 3, d_4 = 3.$ so $r > n$ in this case. in general it's true that $r \geq n.$ Basically we are using the following result: *There exists a (free) basis $\{a_1,\cdots ,a_n \}$ of $A$ and integers $d_1,\cdots ,d_n$ s.t. $\{d_1a_1,\cdots ,d_na_n \}$ is a (free) basis of $B$.* But we can also further factorize $d_i$'s into prime powers. This gives $r \geq n.$

Comment: Your notation made me think you use [this theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_modules_over_a_principal_ideal_domain#Invariant_factor_decomposition).